# Why while authentication using passport.js, I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am writing an application which essentially will list products and allows users to checkout their shopping cart. But I am stuck with this issue while using Passport for user authentication. My facebook authetication works perfectly and captures the user's email address etc., I have been struggling with the Twitter and Google redirects bacxk to localhost (currently working on my laptop). Upon redirecting to localhost, I get following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

my facebook.js passport file looks like below and works perfectly fine

```
'use strict'

const passport = require('passport')
    , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy

const User = require('../models/user')    

let check = x => x === undefined ? 'empty' : x


passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({
        id: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        photo: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.id+"/picture",
        email: check(profile._json.email)
    }, function(err, user) {
        return done( err, user)
    })
}
))
```

And my twitter.js and google.js files look like the below:

```
'use strict'

const passport = require('passport')
    , TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy

const User = require('../models/user') 

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback",
    includeEmail: true
},
function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({
        id: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        photo: profile.photos[0].value,
        email: profile.emails[0].value
    }, function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user)
    })
}
))
```

```
'use strict'

const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy

const User = require('../models/user') 

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({
        id: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        photo: profile.photos[0].value,
        email: profile.emails[0].value
    }, function (err, user) {
        return done(err, user)
    })
}
))
```

my app.js looks like the below:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const favicon = require('serve-favicon')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const{mongoose} = require('./db/index')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)

//================ROUTES
const userRouter = require('./routes/index')
const adminRouter = require('./routes/admin')
const productRouter = require('./routes/products')

//=================MODELS
const Category = require('./models/category')
const Product = require('./models/product')
const User = require('./models/user')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
const logger = require('./log')
const morgan = require('morgan')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(morgan('combined',{'stream': logger.stream}))

//==================SESSIONS
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost/e-commerce'})
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

//==================Navbar
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    Category.find().then(data => {
        res.locals.ctg = data
        next()
    }, (e) => {throw new Error('Unable to find category')})
})

//==================Use Routes
app.use(userRouter)
app.use(adminRouter)
app.use(productRouter)

//======================PASSPORT
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id)
})
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user)
    })
})


//==================Errors
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    const err = new Error('Not found')
    err.status = 404
    next(err)
})


app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    res.render('error')
})


//app.set('port',(process.env.PORT || 3000))
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT,() => logger.info(`${String.fromCodePoint(9749)} is ready on port ${PORT}`))
// app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
//     console.log('running on port',app.get('port'))
// })


module.exports ={app}
```

and my products.js looks like below where I have added the routes:

```
'use strict'

const router = require('express').Router()
const logger = require('../log')
const Category = require('../models/category')
const Product = require('../models/product')

router.get('/navbar', (req,res) => {
    const perPage = 8
    const page = req.query.page || 1
    const ctg = req.query.name


    Product.find({category: req.query.name})
        .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .then(products => {
            Product.count({category: req.query.name})
                .then(count => {
                    res.render('product', {
                        navbar: products,
                        current: page,
                        pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
                        category: ctg
                    })
                }, (e) => {throw new Error('Unable to count!')})
        }, (e) => {throw new Error('Unable to find this product!')})
})

router.get('/single', (req,res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        console.log(req.user)
        res.send('ok')
    }
})



module.exports = router
```

The console gives the following error when trying to use Twitter:

```
GET /auth/twitter 302 855.274 ms - 0
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:24:58 +0000] \"GET /auth/twitter HTTP/1.1\" 302 0 \"http://localhost:3000/login\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
GET /auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 500 1393.641 ms - 1775
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:25:00 +0000] \"GET /auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1\" 500 1775 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
GET /auth/twitter/style.css 404 11.922 ms - 1735
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:25:00 +0000] \"GET /auth/twitter/style.css HTTP/1.1\" 404 1735 \"http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
```

and when trying with Google I get the following:

```
GET /auth/google 302 7.842 ms - 0
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:05:38 +0000] \"GET /auth/google HTTP/1.1\" 302 0 \"http://localhost:3000/login\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
GET /auth/google/callback?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read 500 1031.758 ms - 1775
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:05:54 +0000] \"GET /auth/google/callback?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read HTTP/1.1\" 500 1775 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
GET /auth/google/style.css 404 13.095 ms - 1735
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:05:54 +0000] \"GET /auth/google/style.css HTTP/1.1\" 404 1735 \"http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
GET /auth/google/favicon.ico 404 4.848 ms - 1735
{"message":"::1 - - [25/Mar/2019:14:05:54 +0000] \"GET /auth/google/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 1735 \"http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback?code=4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36\"\n","level":"info"}
```

Please do let me know if you would need any additional info to help me identify the issue with my code here.